# Making MATLAB Code Platform Independent

Tags: java, matlab, converters, simulink, platform

I have a MATLAB code (including Simulink models) which I would like to make platform-independent, i.e., allowing them to run on web browsers and smartphone apps. Would coding it in Java be the best solution? And are there programs which can convert MATLAB code and Simulink models into another programming language easily so that I won't have to re-code everything out again? Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You'll have to recode

> Would coding it in Java be the best solution?

Probably not. I've found that java is hardly ever the best solution. It may be the easiest, but I doubt it's the best. But for web-browsers, AFAIK, you must render some part down to javascript (even if it's just a shim to fetch data running on a server), flash, silverlight*, or java*. For iphone, you need to do it in C, Objective-C, or C++. I think Android uses some kind of java-like/based language, but I don't know. I doubt Win Mobile 8 even has a JVM, but don't really know there.

* Few people like to leave these plugins open. Too easy to exploit and few sites use them.

> And are there programs which can convert MATLAB code and Simulink models into another programming language easily so that I won't have to re-code everything out again?

Mathworks makes an m-code compiler, but you still need a lot of their libraries. It compiles for x86 under Windows and Linux. I think it supports a few other OS's, but all x86 unless they changed it around again. I guess you could try to get MCR working on a phone, but not in a web browser. Realtime Workshop renders simulink models to C, but not if they contain matlab function blocks (or some other blocks, I forget the full list). I hope you have a crap ton of cash, 'cause both those are expensive toolsets.

Comment: It's broadly correct. RTW (now called MATLAB Coder and Simulink Coder) allows you to generate C/C++ code from your Simulink model. If your MATLAB code is part of your model (in a MATLAB Function block), you can also generate code, as long as you restrict yourself to the subset of the MATLAB language supported for code generation. The intended use is generally for running in a real-time on a microprocessor  rather than web deployment. To customise and optimise the code, you'll also need Embedded Coder, and yes all of these are expensive.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, KitsuneYMG and am304. I'll just have to start re-coding everything then.

Comment: @am304 That's an "embedded matlab function" block yes? Different from matlab function block. The people I work for are in the processing of moving everything from 2010b to 2013a, so my knowledge is a bit dated. Sorry

Comment: @KitsuneYMG Correct. That was the "old" name, it's now simply called a MATLAB function block: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html